# Is this a weed growing in my old tomato plant pot?

Tags: weed-control, tomatoes, weeds

Last year I had a tomato plant in this pot, which I cut back at end of the season when it died. In the pot now this is growing. Is this a weed?

[image]

Comment: Let's just say it's not a tomato. Apart from that, the definition of "weed" is "plant growing in a place where we don't want it to" - which we can't answer for you. But I guess the real question is "What is this plant?".

Answer (score 1):

By the very definition, a weed is an unwanted plant.  If you did not plant it there, it is a weed and it certainly does not look like a tomato.  I say get rid of it and grow something you want to in it's place.

Comment: I had my share of volunteers as well but find that they don't give the same quality or quantity of produce. I don't wait any longer to find out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks at first glance like a member of the beet family-not a silverbeet (leaves aren't crinkled) -possibly a variety of beetroot with those central reddish veins. As others have said, definitely not a tomato or even a "tomato" if you know what I mean!!